# Server side rendering based on agent

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I want to do conditional server side rendering (PHP) and client rendering (Angular).

Basically we have headless documentation repository which provides content via REST API.

Angular application for this headless CMS is already available.

Now for search engine indexing we need to support server-side rendering and PHP looks to be good candidate.

So when any user search on Google/Search engine, and if our content matches, search engine will display it in results.  Now when user clicks on that link, our PHP page will redirect it to angular application.

Any help will be appreciated for solving this.

Comment: This is where SSR with Angular Universal can help.

Comment: So you don't have SSR setup yet? I'd start experimenting with that, because it's a lot of getting used to. I'm using ASP.NET Core + angular, but in any way there should be smth for php too. In essence, [your php application contains a middleware]( https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-ssr-under-the-hood-asp-net-core-51562b70e511) which starts an express server. On each request, the middleware sends another request to the express server, and Node executes the export, and returns the output